# Issue with FC-51 IR sensor

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio, sensor

I am developing a robot with raspberry pi. To detect obstacles I am using `FC-51` IR sensor. This is my current code.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
ObstaclePin = 18
tServoPin = 15
GPIO.setup(tServoPin, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(ObstaclePin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(tServoPin, GPIO.OUT)
tPwm = GPIO.PWM(tServoPin, 50)
tPwm.start(0)

def loop():
    while True:
        if (1 == GPIO.input(ObstaclePin)):
            print ("Barrier is detected !")
            turn_right(tPwm)
        else:
            print ("No barrier found !")


def turn_right(tPwm):
     for i in range(90, 180):
          positiont = 1./18.*(i)+2
          tPwm.ChangeDutyCycle(positiont)
          time.sleep(0.02)
     for i in range(180, 90, -1):
          positiont = 1./18.*(i)+2
          tPwm.ChangeDutyCycle(positiont)
          time.sleep(0.05)

def destroy():
    GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  
        destroy()
```

This above code works fine when I comment `turn_right` line in `loop()` function. That is it print "Barrier is detected !" whenever I close a object to it and when I take object away from it the obstacle indicator turn off. But when I uncomment that code line IR sensor's obstacle indicator keeps blinking after obstacle detection. But there is no object close to it. While blinking it is also not fully illuminated. And servo does not stop. I think IR sensor keep blinking it's indicator as a reason for this

[image].

I have connected IR sensor to pin 16 and servo to pin 15 in Raspberry pi. and both VCC and GND connect to a bread board. And an Arduino supply 5v for the bread board.

I can not understand the logic behind this.
What am i doing wrong here??

Any help would be great
Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: The code has nothing to light a bulb.  Could you explain what you think the code does and explain the "bulb"?

Comment: I don't see any code to turn on an LED,  but turnRight(tPWM) appears to block, so if an LED was turned on, it won't be turned off until turnRight() is finished. Robot code needs to be asynchronous in order to not have these problems. you can do this with threads or with interrupts. Also it would be nice to say you're not only developing this on the Pi, but also that it's written in Python and which version.

Comment: @joan I mean, when code is not running IR sensor works as expected. that is when ever i put objects close it will turn on green light and off when i take object away. but while running code with turn_right() it does off the green lights even their is no object. And also turn_right() does not stop. it keep running

Comment: @NomadMaker Thank you for your ideas. I am using python 3.5.3 for this. Problem is turn_right() function keep running. Can you explain it more, i mean do to this with threads

Comment: You really need to clean up the code. It isn't indented properly in your sample. Which wouldn't be as big a deal, but python uses indentation as a part of the syntax. What I was thinking, was that turn_right takes time to complete. This means that if you have a new obstacle before then that it won't be detected. If I knew what you meant by "lighting a bulb" I'd be able to make a possible better suggestion. I don't believe it's part of your code.

Comment: @NomadMaker I don't want to light any bulb. i just want to detects obstacle and turn robots using servo motor.

Comment: "...ir sensor keep lighting the bulb ..." Your words - what bulb?

Comment: Is the output after the motor finished is the "while True" loop still running? If so, the output should be a long list of "Barrier is detected !" lines on standard output. If not, please put a print statement at the end of turn_right() to see how long that function takes to run.

Comment: @joan My bad.. I meant the "obstacle LED", FC-51 has two small LED red(power) and  yellow(obstacle)

Comment: @NomadMaker Yes, the output is long list of "Barrier is detected !". I also put print statement. It is also printing as a loop.. doesn't stop.. While looping the obstacle indicator of my sensor is blinking..

Comment: Because you told it to loop. Please modify the code sample in your question to match the code you're running. Likewise, please change the text of the question so that people aren't confused by the "bulb" that you wrote. If you can, on the first while loop, on the if statement, add an else clause with a print statement "No barrier detected" so that we can see the details of what's going on.

Comment: @NomadMaker I have edited my question as you suggested.

Comment: As long as your sensor believes there is an obstacle, turn_right() will be called with every pass through the while loop. Does the servo turn from 90 to 180 degrees and back again between every "Barrier is detected !" line? What pins are you connecting the sensor to? And what pins is the servo connected to? Please put these as part of the question. I'm thinking now that this is a power problem, with the motor causing a voltage drop or voltage spike which might effect the sensor. But I'm shooting in the dark on this one.

Comment: @NomadMaker I have edited my question. I get 5v power supply via Arduino board to the bread board.

Comment: @NomadMaker I also think it is due to power problem. Because when I run only the servo in loop and connect all three wire of IR sensor, the sensor is blinking.. That indicate a power problem. Isn't it? But I am new to this stuff. Can guide me?

Comment: I don't know anything about the sensor. But I do think that a power problem is the most likely thing. Do you have access to a larger 5v USB charger? What else do you have plugged into your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @NomadMaker I plugged raspberry pi to my laptop via USB cable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80158/discussion-between-nomadmaker-and-iuhettiarachchi).